# XCode not loading app onto iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode

XCode has suddenly stopped installing my app on my iPhone. It was working fine and has now just stopped.

When I click on the run button it says Build Succeeded but doesn't put the app on the iPhone.

Do I have to do something other than press the run button?

The iPhone is connected and appears as the destination of the run.

Comment: 1. Delete you app from device.
2. Restart your device.
3. Restart xCode. 
4. Try again.
5. If again it is not working then check your provisioning profile.

Comment: Restarting device seemed to do the job thanks.

Comment: That really worked @BillNoble